# How to redirect to React/Vue route after user authorize via oauth2 twitter or discord through passport?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vue.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

So I want to make authentication so that a user can authenticate by twitter and discord. So I created developer accounts in twitter and discord developer portal. then I made passport strategy for both socials. For reference I am providing my strategy credentials in the following(for twitter):

```
{
    consumerKey: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:9000/api/auth/twitter/callback",
    includeEmail: true,
}
```

the discord one is similar to twitter.

Routes for twitter are:

```
router.get("/auth/discord", passport.authenticate("discord"))
router.get(
  "/auth/discord/redirect",
  passport.authenticate("discord"),
  (req, res) => {
    res.json({
      success: true,
      user: req.user,
    })
  }
)
```

Now my question is after a user authorizes, how can I redirect the user to SPA route (React/Vue)?

Comment: As I can see in the passport.js documentation, there are two parameters available when you call `passport.authenticate` function. These two are: `successRedirect` and `failureRedirect`. "The first will redirect the user to the sigin page. The second will process the authentication result when the user is redirected back."
Check this out https://www.passportjs.org/tutorials/auth0/routes/ :)

Comment: This is the answer. can you write it to answer ? I will tick it as the answer

Comment: Yep, sure ;) Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in the passport.js documentation, there are two parameters available when you call
`passport.authenticate` function. These two are: `successRedirect` and `failureRedirect`.

> The first will redirect the user to the sigin page. The second will process the authentication result when the user is redirected back.

Check this out ;) [passportjs.org/tutorials/auth0/routes](https://passportjs.org/tutorials/auth0/routes)

Answer (score 1):

That was very simple indeed. I just needed to add redirect to my frontend url

```
router.get("/auth/twitter", passport.authenticate("twitter"))
router.get(
  "/auth/twitter/callback",
  passport.authenticate("twitter", {
    failureRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/login",
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000")
  }
)
```